# How do I make this print button loop through all iframes instead of just one?

Tags: javascript, iframe, printing, internet-explorer-11

My iframes:

```
<iframe name="pictoframeaerial" 
src="https://explorer.pictometry.com/login.php""></iframe>
<iframe name="pictoframeoblique" 
src="https://explorer.pictometry.com/login.php" "></iframe>
<iframe id="street" class="zoom" name="street" 
src="http://localhost/streetview.html" ></iframe>
```

My button:

```
$('#print').click(function ()
{
    var contentWindow = document.getElementById("street").contentWindow;
    var result = contentWindow.document.execCommand('print', false, null);
    if(!result)  contentWindow.print();
})
```

Thanks. I have seen this done with the window.frames print method. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refer to the following code:

```
function printPage() {

    window.print();

    for (var k = 0; k < window.frames.length; k++) {
        window.frames[k].focus();
        window.frames[k].print();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. This code does not work with ie 11. The other one does. Although I want to loop through multiple frames rather than one.